# Forward blog requests to another URL

Tags: htaccess

Inside of this .htaccess file in the root, I need to add a command that will forward the traffic from one domain to another.  Can someone help?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Many duplicates, depending on whether you want to forward all to the homepage of the new domain or whether you have copied URL structure to the new domain. A couple of examples: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227554/redirect-old-domain-posts-to-new-domain-homepage https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247185/redirect-301-old-url-to-new-url

Answer (score 0):

In your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.newdomainyouknow.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR in your subfolder `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomainyouknow.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can remove all other entries.

But this will move all request from one domain to the new domain :
for example
`http://oldandboringdomain.com/blog/cool-staf`
will be redirected to
`http://www.newdomainyouknow.com/blog/cool-staf`

With **301 redirect** (permanent) which mean cachable by the browser and not only.

Comment: This didn't work.  I'm trying to do this:

domaina.com/blog to domainb.com/blog

I also want to catch any blog post URLs such as:

domaina.com/blog/story to domainb.com/blog/story

Comment: @MichaelHarmon I have updated my answer this now will work as you expect. Remember to flush the cache or open a private window to see it in action. Or You can test it with 302 redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm getting the following error in my browser.  I've placed your code in the .htaccess file in the /blog root:

www.domainb.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: If you have leave your `.htaccess` file in the root folder as is. And only change the `.htaccess` of your folder `blog` it should work. Maybe your browser has cached the redirect. Try with a new private window and test it as a 302. I have tested again and it redirect me as expected.

Comment: Here's a little more information if it will help.  Thanks for your continued responses.

I am working on a website that uses OSCommerce.  Outside of OSCommerce this works fine.  Inside of OSCommerce pages though, the redirect is being ignored.

It has something to do with the .htaccess file in the /shop directory.  Here is what is in it:

    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteRule ^enclosures-enclosure-guidelines-c-229_675.html$ /resources#nema-guidelines [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^mc/(.*)$ mc.php?keywords=$1`

Comment: @MichaelHarmon I see the base as `/shop/` this is different and correctly not redirect you as your question was about the `/blog/` and we add the rule to redirect all `^blog/(.*)` traffic to the new domain.